# REDIS: How to use a Lexicographical Index to save ranges of data

Tags: redis, sortedset, lexicographic, lexicographic-ordering

**Background Information**

I need to query a value using a key, but the key needs to be evaluated in a specific order of precedence where the order is:

- if an exact match exists, use the value associated with the matching key
- if the key falls into a range of keys defined in the db, use the value associated with the range.
- if there is no matching key, use a default

To better explain the problem, I'll draw a hash like this:

```
'northam' hash
key       value
=====================
12345     abc
default   ddd
2000[0-10]  bbb
```

Using the above storage construct, I need to be able:

- to query using key 12345 and have the db return abc because it found an exact match.
- If i query using key '33333' then I just want to return the value ddd associated with the "default" key since I don't have a key/value for 33333.
- If i query using key '2000' or '2004' i want it to find the value bbb.

**Question**

In REDIS, can I somehow create a key like '2000[0-10]'?
Is there a better way to do this?  I know I can programatically expand 2000[0-10] and store each value as a separate entry in the table.  But if the user updates this range and changes it to 2000[15-21], then the clean up is going to be a bit messy.

**What I've Tried So Far**

I've been playing around with sorted sets?  I don't fully understand how they work.  But so far, I've tried something like this:

```
127.0.0.1:6379[1]> zadd northam 2000 ddd 2002 ddd
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379[1]>
```

And now I'm trying to see if I can query for 2000 (or any other value within the range of 2000-2010) and get "ddd" back.  but it's not working.

**EDIT 1**

So after reading a little bit about indexing / secondary indexes, this is the prototype data structure I've been playing with:

```
127.0.0.1:6379[3]> zadd northamerica 0 2000:2010:1234512345
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379[3]> zadd northamerica 0 2011:2014:00000000000
(integer) 1
```

The first record, i'm trying to say the starting number in my range is 2000 and the ending number is 2010.  For any numbers that fall withing that range, use the value 1234512345
But now I need to know how to execute a query.  So for example, if the user requests to know what value to use for key "2009" I don't know how to run the query against this structure to find that it should use 1234512345

**EDIT 2**

So in the end, I think I've decided to use a lexicographic index, as shown above, and then bake logic into the application itself to interpret.  So for example,

```
127.0.0.1:6379[3]> zrange northamerica 0 -1
1) "2000:2010:12312312345"
2) "2011:2014:00000000000"
3) "2015:2015:11111111111"
127.0.0.1:6379[3]>
```

The application could query all records for north america and then when it gets the above list back, it could split (into arrays) each record by ":" to determine what ranges exist.

Comment: Have you tried the approaches described in https://redis.io/topics/indexes?

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'll give it a read and see I get some pointers.  IN the meantime, if anyone else has some feedback, I'm listening.

Comment: It may be possible to do this in Redis, but quite frankly, I wouldn't want to. I would probably use something like Postgres range types and indexes for this, if that were an option.

Comment: ok. unfortunately, i have to find a solution in redis.

Comment: Would you be willing to explode the range, i.e. insert an entry for 2000, a separate entry for 2001, etc.? That plus scoring (to prefer exact years) might be a workable approach.

Comment: @mwp the problem with exploding the range is the maintenance. If today they want the range to be 100-200 and then tomorrow it's 200-229 it's a real pain to maintain / clean up the old stuff.

Comment: @dot Agreed, although I'm not sure it's that much worse than doing the range logic in your application code. I think it all boils down to your performance requirements. If you can meet the client SLA doing the logic in your application code, that's fine then. If you need better performance you might need a different solution, whether that's exploding the range or writing the lookup in Redis Lua or something else entirely.